# Create image with php and show it in joomla template

Tags: php, joomla

I have a simple function in a class:

```
<?php>class cre
{
    function creimage()
        {
             header("Content-type: image/gif");
             $im = imagecreate (100, 50);
             imagegif($im);
             imagedestroy($im);
        }
};?>
```

In model file:

```
<?php class mymodel extends JModel
{
    var myclass;
    function __construct()
        {
            myclass = new cre();
        }
    function getMyclass()
        {
            return $this->myclass;
        }
};?>
```

view.html.php file:

```
<?php class myview extends JView
{
    function display($tpl = null)
         {
             $myclass = & $this->get('Myclass');
             parent::display($tpl);
         }
};?>
```

I call this function in a joomla template with giving src attribute of image tag such manner:

`<img src='<?php echo $this->myclass->creimage();?>'>`

but in spite of I get the image, I can see the binary code of the image in the browser.
What is the error?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `creimage` method is sending out the actual image data, which you are sticking inside of your `src=''` attribute, that won't work.

You need to put a URL in the `src` attribute:

```
<img src='/path/to/imagescript.php'>
```

Then create a PHP script there that sends out the image data with the appropriate header.